SmoothKernelDistribution only uses 1 core
I have a huge amount of datasets, each containing many elements, and trying to convert it to PDF using SmoothKernelDistribution. I see that applying it to 1 dataset only uses 1 core out of my 8. If trying to do ParallelTable of SmoothKernelDistributions for many datasets, Mathematica gets stuck. Could you please tell me how to parallelize it in either of two ways?

What do you mean by "gets stuck"? Can you add a sample of your dataset and the code you tried?
